# Structure pointer assignment in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

What's wrong with this code, specially in check function? I assigned the address of `temp1` in the root pointer array. But I can't access it from the main function, although they gave the same address as output.

```
struct block {
  int counter=0;
  struct block *arr[4];
  bool is_leaf;
  string val[3];

} root;

void check() {
  struct block temp1;
  temp1.is_leaf=true;
  temp1.val[0]="Sy";
  root.arr[1]=&temp1;
  cout<<root.arr[1]->val[0]<<endl;
  cout<<root.arr[1]<<endl; //block address
}

int main(){

  string s1;

  root.val[2]=s1;
  struct block temp;
  temp.val[0]="wewrq";
  root.arr[0]=&temp;
  check();
  cout<<root.arr[0]->val[0]<<endl;  // did work
  cout<<root.arr[1]<<endl;          // same block address
  cout<<root.arr[1]->val[0]<<endl;  // didn't work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of `struct block temp1` is limited before `check()` returns. Once `check()` returns you cannot access `temp1` anymore even if you have its address stored in another global structure instance.

Depending on your actual usage, you may declare `temp1` as `static struct block temp1;` instead, or you may need to redesign the code structure.

Answer (score 1):

`temp1` will vanish on exiting its scope (returning the function `check()` in this case), so it cannot be accessed after that from `main()` function without invoking *undefined behavior*.

One of ways to make it accessible is make the variable static like

```
static struct block temp1;
```

so that there will be only one instance of `temp1` throughout the execution of the program.